# Declare a static variable using an enumerator C# (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, enums

Just a simple question, but I cannot find it.

I have this code in 1 file:

```
namespace Models
{
    public enum MyEnvironment
    {
        Development,
        Testing,
        Acceptance,
        Production
    }
}
```

And in my program.cs file:

```
global using Models
static MyEnvironment CurrentEnvironment = MyEnvironment.Development;
```

With this code I want to set a Environment that is global accessible through my whole code. But I get the error:

> the modifier 'static' is not valid for this item

Why can't I use my enumerator in a static variable?

Comment: Firstly, there is no enumerator here it is just an "enum" or an "enumeration type". Secondly, you can't just add a variable on it's own, it needs to be inside a class.

Comment: Ah check, indeed my static enum was not in a class. Now it is, and it works. Thanks! I knew it was something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't just add a variable on its own, it needs to be inside a class. So your code should be:

```
global using Models

public static class GlobalVariables // Feel free to choose a better name
{
    public static MyEnvironment CurrentEnvironment = MyEnvironment.Development;
}
```

Also, note there is no "enumerator" here it is just an "enum" or an "enumeration type".